# Show that curve has a constant torsion.

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Let $t\mapsto \beta(t)\in S^2 \subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular curve. We define $$t\mapsto \gamma(t):=\int_{t_0}^t \beta(t)\times \beta'(t)dt.$$ Show that $\gamma$ has a constant torsion.

---

We have that
\begin{align*}
\gamma'&=\beta \times \beta',\\
\gamma''&=\beta \times \beta'',\\
\gamma'''&=\beta' \times \beta''+\beta \times \beta'''
\end{align*} 
We can calculate torsion with the following formula
$$\tau=\dfrac{|\gamma',\gamma'',\gamma'''|}{|\gamma'\times \gamma''|^2}=\dfrac{|\beta \times \beta',\beta \times \beta'',\beta' \times \beta''+\beta \times \beta'''|}{|(\beta \times \beta')\times (\beta \times \beta'')|^2}$$
I know that $$(\beta \times \beta')\times (\beta \times \beta'')=|\beta,\beta',\beta''|\beta-|\beta,\beta',\beta|\beta''=|\beta,\beta',\beta''|\beta$$
But what now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\beta \times \beta'$, $\beta \times \beta''$ and $\beta \times \beta'''$ are linear dependent (all three are orthogonal to $\beta$), hence 
$$ \det(\beta \times \beta', \beta \times \beta'',\beta \times \beta''') = 0 $$
For the other summand in the numerator, due to 
\begin{align*}
  \det(a,b,c \times d) &= a \cdot \bigl(b \times (c\times d)\bigr)\\
                       &= a \cdot \bigl((b\cdot d)c - (b \cdot c)d\bigr)\\
                       &= (b\cdot d)(a \cdot c) - (b \cdot c)(a \cdot d)
\end{align*}
We have
\begin{align*}
   \det(\beta \times \beta', \beta \times \beta'', \beta' \times \beta'')
   &= \bigl((\beta \times \beta'') \cdot \beta'\bigr) \bigl((\beta \times \beta') \cdot \beta'' \bigr) \\
   &= \det(\beta', \beta, \beta'') \det(\beta'', \beta, \beta')\\
   &= -\det(\beta, \beta', \beta'')^2
\end{align*}
As the denominator equals $\det(\beta, \beta', \beta'')^2$ (note that $|\beta| = 1$), the quotient is constant.

Comment: How do I conclude that they are linearly dependent? I don't really get that part. If vectors are orthogonal, then they are linearly dependent. Is that your statement?

Comment: Now, but $U := \{\beta\}^\bot$ is a two-dimensional subspace. Any three vectors in $U$ must be dependent.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you. :D

Comment: @martini: What are some non-trivial examples of variable curvature and constant torsion ? Thanks.