# Which curves have constant torsion?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

I know from the Frenet-Serret equations that if a curve $r(s)$ (parametrized by arc-length) has constant torsion $\tau \neq 0$, then
$$
b' = \tau n \Rightarrow b \times b' = \tau b \times n = -\tau v \Rightarrow r'= -\frac 1\tau b \times b
$$
Where $n$ is the unit normal vector to the velocity $v$ and $b = v \times n$. I can also find a formula for the curvature $k$ (which I assume is non-zero everywhere on the curve) by recalling that
\begin{align}
n' &= -\tau b - k v
\\
b'' &= -\tau(\tau b - kv)
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
b \cdot (b' \times b'') &= -\tau^2 b \cdot( n \times (\tau b + k v)) 
\\ 
&= \tau^2 (\tau b \cdot (n \times b) + k b \cdot (n \times v))
\\
& = \tau^2k b \cdot n \times v
\\
& = \tau^2 k 
\end{align}
From this I get that $r$ has constant torsion only if $r' = -\frac 1\tau b \times b'$ where $||b|| = 1$ and $\tau ^{-2} b \cdot (b' \times b'') = k(s) \neq 0$ for all $s$. Conversely, by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1708903/show-that-curve-has-a-constant-torsion) question, I know that these conditions also imply the curve $r = -\frac 1 \tau \int b \times b'$ has constant torsion. My question is, are these the most specific constraints? It seems to me that they are fairly loose, all I have to do is pick some smooth trajectory on the unit sphere and satisfy $b \cdot (b' \times b'') \neq 0$ everywhere, but perhaps this last requirement narrows down the possible curves and I am not seeing how. Can we say anything more about constant torsion curves?

Comment: The Frenet-Serret formulas and existence-uniqueness results from differential equations show there is a unique curve (up to rigid motions) for any choice of nice curvature function $\kappa(s)$ and nice torsion function $\tau(s)$ (of the arclength parameter $s$).

Answer (score 1):

If we consider surfaces it may be easier:

If $(k_1,k_2)$ are (Euler) principal curvatures (on a negative Gauss curvature then directions along which *geodesic* torsion is constant is given by

$$ 2 \sqrt2 \tau =\frac{k_1-k_2}{\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}}.$$

This follows from Mohr's circles wit a
fixed point.

Examples are: Asymptotes of a pseudosphere, central asymptotes of right/left helicoids among similar others.

The generalized Frenet Serret including $k_g$ geodesic curvature may give a solution but now I cannot derive it.